Can I connect Android Studio to my phone for debugging if my computer is using the phone’s hotspot?
I usually connect my phone to Android Studio for debugging over Wi-Fi, but right now my computer is connected to the internet using my phone's mobile hotspot.
Is there a way to still connect Android Studio to my phone for debugging in this setup (without cable)? I’ve already turned on Developer Options and WiFi Debugging, when I try to turn on Wi-Fi debugging, it shows the message "Please connect to a Wi-Fi network"
Any tips or steps to make this work would be great. Thanks!

You can easily connect your device with Android Studio over Wifi using the "Pair device using Wi-Fi" option. Since a Hotspot establishes a Wifi network where both devices will be part of I see no reason why the device shouldn't be able to connect to Android Studio in that scenario as well. I haven't tried, though. Have you? What issues are you facing? Please [edit] your question and specify what exactly you have problems with.

Can you clarify if the machine where Android Studio is running on handles the Wifi as a metered connection? If it does, does the problem still persist when you change it?

@tyg I think the issue is that my phone is the hotspot, so it's not connected to WiFi itself. WiFi debugging needs the phone on a Wi-Fi network
